# Will the new modules and units be part of Google Classroom API?

Tags: google-classroom

Regarding the new described features in https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/9048510

Will the units and modules mentioned be supported by the Google Classroom API?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [link](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/9048510) you've provided, units or modules is still supported as there is a feature to *Organize the assignments and questions by grouping them into modules and units.* You may follow this [Google Classroom API Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/classroom/release-notes) for any updates.